# Text alignment in a div contained into a footer

Tags: html, css, footer, text-align

I can't get the text in the footer placed in the right position, just as the image below:
[image: Desired aspect]

I've been making changes to the code from a template and now the text is in the upper part and some blank spots appear, specially on Chrome browsers:
[image]

The web is [here](http://www.xente.mundo-r.com/turkish/ecomir_2/index.html) and these are the links to the [html](http://pastebin.com/wkZssYdi) and the [css](http://pastebin.com/7s6FsM6y)

Update: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/luispradoa/p45dE/) added.

```
<footer class="aligncenter">
    <div class="wrapper" id="bottom_footer">
         <h2 class="hidden">xxxx Footer</h2>

        <section>
            <div class="left_column">
                 <h4>OFICINAS CENTRALES</h4>

                <p>xxxxxxx xxxx, 35</p>
                <P>xxxx x</p>
                <p>Tlfo xxxxx Fax xxxx</p>
            </div>
            <!-- left_column-->
            <div class="mid_column"><span class="helper"></span>
                <img src="images/eccWhite_200.png" width="400" height="120" />
            </div>
            <div class="right_column">
                 <h4> xxxxx ESTRUCTURAS SL</h4>

                <p>estructuras construcciones y contratas</p>
                <p>info@xxxx</p>
            </div>
            <!--right_column-->
        </section>
        <!-- class="container"-->
    </div>
    <!-- wrapper footer-->
</footer>
```

Could you please show me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: *note answer, but advice* You should really look into these http://freehtml5templates.com/ and http://getbootstrap.com/ :)

Comment: Your site is coming up as "malicious" under my works filter.  If you can jsfiddle the footer, I'd be happy to help!

Comment: The HTML/CSS seems pretty messed up :S if you create a fiddle with the relevant code we can give proper help. If you can't, you can alway try this : add `background: #ccc;` to `#bottom_footer section` in CSS but it would only be a patch and wouldn't solve the issue in a proper way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<footer id="footer">
                    <h2 class="hidden">Ecomir Footer</h2>
                <div class="left_column">
                                  <h4>OFICINAS CENTRALES</h4>
                                  <span>Almirantes Matos, 35</span>
                                  <span>36002 PONTEVEDRA</span>
                                  <span>Tlfo 986869940 Fax 98685362<span>
                </div><!-- left_column--> 

                <div class="right_column">
                                  <h4> ECOMIR ESTRUCTURAS SL</h4>
                                  <span>estructuras construcciones y contratas</span>
                                  <span>info@ecomir.es</span>
                </div><!--right_column-->
    </footer>
```

css

```
.hidden {
           display: none;
           visibility: hidden;
        }
#footer h4{
    line-height: 1em;
    margin:10px 0 0 0;
}
#footer{
    width: 1100px;
    height: 120px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: -560px;
    left: 50%;
    background-color: #CCC;
    background-image: url(http://www.xente.mundo-r.com/turkish/ecomir_2/images/eccWhite_200.png); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 400px 120px;
    background-position: center;

}
.left_column{
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #FF0080;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
.right_column{
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #FF00FF;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend against using `float:left;` on the left and middle column. Since your content is not likely to change significantly there is one thing I might do. Give your footer `position:relative` and position your `.right-column` with `position:absolute; bottom:0; right:0;`. This will ensure that your right column is far to the right, and aligned to the bottom of the footer.

Overall, the styles in the footer seem like they are trying to be 'not a table' and end up being kind of messy for it. If you want semantic markup that still behaves like a table, try http://960.gs/.

Answer (score 0):

Not able To fix it complete but the following point will help you a lot

1. I looked into your code not completely but found that you used
   `margin-left` property although your left right div are 25 % and
   center one is 50 % So there is not space for that margin . IF you
   remove `margin-left:10px` (I suppose in your code). The White lines
   will be removed and you can align text by setting `margin-top`.
2. I have not studied your whole code but not able to find `clear:both`
   property as the bottom three div float. So do that as it is a good
   practice and I think it will help in solving your issue
3. Either set background of section to `#ccc` or use `padding` not `margin`

Hope this help.....

Answer (score 0):

you can simple use this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/erenyener/32hEM/)

I tried to solve it but stylesheet little bit messed up in my opinion, so just remove the footer at all then try to apply your footer in your own style sheet just like I created.

Be careful while choosing class names because, if there will be a overload , it will messed up again

```
.footer
{
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
    width:400px;
    height:100px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    font-size:9px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked the HTML version, in your code you unnecessary use `section` remove that first.
by removing this you can remove the while space.

there are a lots of things which need to fixed ..but here is work around to vertically align the text.

```
.right_column
{
width: 25%; /*remove this line**/
display: inline; /*remove this line**/
}
```